# Display problems with a tikz-cd diagram

Tags: math-mode, tikz-cd

I use tikz-cd package to construct a math diagram. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4 paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathdots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep = tiny, row sep = small]
& & & & & &M   \arrow[hookleftarrow]{dr} & & & & &\\
& & & & &M_{n-1} \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} \arrow[hookleftarrow]{dr} &  &N_{p-1} \arrow[hookleftarrow]{dr} & & & & \\
& & & &M_{n-2} \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} \arrow[hookleftarrow]{dr} & &M'_{n-1}  \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} & &N_{p-2} \arrow[hookleftarrow]{dr} & & & \\
& & & \iddots  \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} & &M'_{n-2} \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} & & & & \ddots \arrow[hookleftarrow]{dr} & & \\
& &M_1 \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} \arrow[hookleftarrow]{dr} & & \iddots \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} & & & & & & N_1 \arrow[hookleftarrow]{dr} & \\
& M_0 \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} \arrow[equal]{dr} & & M'_1 \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} & & & & & & & & N_0 \\
& &M'_0 \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} & & & & & & & & &
\end{tikzcd} 

\end{document}
```

I get this diagram:
[image: Diagram]

It doesn't look so good. I tried so many things to make the picture look better, but I get no relevant results. The big problem is with that diagonal dots. Can someone help me to improve my code? Thank you!
Also, a want to label this diagram such that under it would be "Fig.1". I mention that this diagram has to appear in the middle of a proof (in the proof enviroment).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem are the cells with different widths. You can use `between origins` to fix the issue.

I also changed the dots to be “rotated `\cdots`”. The commands `\updots` and `\downdots` have an optional argument to fine tune the angle for different situations (default 45).

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\updots[1][45]{%
  \makebox[1em]{\smash{\rotatebox[origin=c]{#1}{$\cdots\!$}}\vphantom{$|$}}%
}
\newcommand\downdots[1][45]{%
  \makebox[1em]{\smash{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-#1}{$\cdots\!$}}\vphantom{$|$}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep ={2.75em,between origins}, row sep = {2.75em,between origins}]
& & & & & &M   \arrow[hookleftarrow]{dr} & & & & &\\
& & & & &M_{n-1} \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} \arrow[hookleftarrow]{dr} &  &N_{p-1} \arrow[hookleftarrow]{dr} & & & & \\
& & & &M_{n-2} \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} \arrow[hookleftarrow]{dr} & &M'_{n-1}  \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} & &N_{p-2} \arrow[hookleftarrow]{dr} & & & \\
& & & \updots  \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} & &M'_{n-2} \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} & & & & \downdots \arrow[hookleftarrow]{dr} & & \\
& &M_1 \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} \arrow[hookleftarrow]{dr} & & \updots \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} & & & & & & N_1 \arrow[hookleftarrow]{dr} & \\
& M_0 \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} \arrow[equal]{dr} & & M'_1 \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} & & & & & & & & N_0 \\
& &M'_0 \arrow[hookrightarrow]{ur} & & & & & & & & &
\end{tikzcd} 

\end{document}
```

[image]